# grails apns plugin : SSLHandshakeException

Tags: ios, grails, apple-push-notifications

I'm using the grails apns plugin to send push notification to ios devices :

when i try to send the push i always get this error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

the code i use to send the push :

```
String payload = APNS.newPayload().alertBody(message).sound("default").build();

apnsService.push(token, payload)
```

any idea about the cause if this error ? i tried to regenerate the certificate (.p12 file ) but still having the same error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a certificate issue , after generating another .p12 file it finally worked :)